# A Java generic class will miss generic info on all fields if this class is used in non-generic way?

Tags: java

There is a generic class:

```
class Test<T> {
    T genericTypeField;
    List<String> list;
}

void method1(Test test) {
    for (String value : test.list) { // Compiler error

    }

    // Correct
    for (Object value : test.list) {

    }
}

void method2(Test<?> test) {
    // Correct
    for (String value : test.list) {

    }
}
```

It seems that if use a generic class in non-generic way, all generic fields in this class will lose the generic info.

Does the Java specification has any description about this?

Comment: why are methods defined outside the class?, also post the entire compiler error message

Comment: @Ramanlfc I think these methods are not inside the class. They are separate methods which use the Test class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `test` in `method1(Test test)` is a `raw type`.

This is the normal behaviour of `Raw types` in Java. It's well declared [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8). The important note for your case is:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Comment: The specific reason why this is happening is this line in the specification: "The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C."

Comment: @Powerlord thanks for your info, updated my ans as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you not provide generic type it always take as object

if you want to use string use like

```
   void method1(Test<String> test) {
     for (String value : test.list) { // This Compiler 
     }
   }
```